# Define ENV variable per stage in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've define my pipe line in gitlab CI as below:

```
dev-build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    VERSION: "dev"
    BASE_URL: "dev.example.com"
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg VERSION=${VERSION} --build-arg BASE_URL=${BASE_URL} -t example:${VERSION} .
    - docker push example:${VERSION}
  only:
    - dev

dev-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    VERSION: "dev"
  script:
    - ssh root@myserver.co, "docker rm -f example_beta; docker pull example:${VERSION} && docker run -d --name example_beta --publish 7733:80 example:beta"
  only:
    - dev
```

How could I define env vars only once in stage and not redefine them in each job?

Comment: simply define them in a `variables:` section outside your stage defs, i.e. at the root of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Use variables outside of each stage:

```
variables:
  DEV_VERSION: "dev"

dev-build:
  blahblah

dev-deploy:
  blahblah
```

Comment: what if I need same var to have different values for stages ?